# Unable to access component state in withFormik handleSubmit

Tags: forms, reactjs

I am using formik (https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) for forms of my react application.
I want to be able to update component state to show a success message after handleSubmit completed successfully.
But I am unable to achieve that. I am getting errors.

```
export default withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues ({ email }) {
    return {
      email: email || ''
    };
  },
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email('Email not valid').required('Email is required')
  }),
  handleSubmit(values, { resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting }) {

    Accounts.forgotPassword({
      email: values.email
    }, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        setErrors({ email: 'Error: ' + error.reason });
      } else {
        this.setState({success: 'Success: Check your inbox for a reset link!'});
        resetForm();
      }
      setSubmitting(false);
    });
  }
})(RecoverPassword);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't access to wrapped component from a higher order component.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access a wrapped component's state from a higher-order component. Formik has a built-in errors and status handling setters and getters.

```
export default withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues ({ email }) {
    return {
      email: email || ''
    };
  },
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email('Email not valid').required('Email is required')
  }),
  handleSubmit(values, { resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting, setStatus }) {
    Accounts.forgotPassword({
      email: values.email
    }, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        setErrors({ email: 'Error: ' + error.reason });
      } else {
        resetForm();
        setStatus('Check your inbox for a reset link.');
        // setStatus is part of the "formik bag".
      }
      setSubmitting(false);
    });
  }
})(RecoverPassword);
```